# How to compare values from keyboard input? JAVA

Tags: java, input, compare

How could I compare two values from the keyboard input? I mean, I have this code:

```
int row, col;   
for (int i = 1; i <= movements; i++) {
    row = scan.nextInt();
    col = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Imagine that I have 4 movements, for example: 1 1 , 1 2 , 2 1 , 2 2 . I want to compare if second movement (1 2) is equals to first (1 1), third (2 1) to second (1 2)...

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Look into encapsulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use temp variable say  prevoousrow & prevoouscol and compare them like below.

```
int row=-1, col=-1,prevoousrow=-1,prevoouscol=-1 ;   
for (int i = 1; i <= movements; i++) {

    row = scan.nextInt();
    col = scan.nextInt();

    if((prevoousrow == row)  && (prevoouscol == col))
    {
      //duplicate/same movement
    }

    prevoousrow = row;
    prevoouscol = col;
}
```